# Python syntax switching between 2 and 3

Tags: python

I've recently started having a weird bug with my python scripts. It seems like it's syntax switches between python 2 and 3 randomly when running the script. For instance, I'll write a script using the `input()` command, and it'll work fine for a couple hours, then start giving me an error even if I don't change a single thing in the code, and want me to switch `input()` to `raw_input()` in order for it to work again.

And the same will happen in reverse. I'll write a code with `raw_input()` since it doesn't like `input()`, and a few hours later it'll make me switch it. It does this with all syntax, not just the inputs. The other main one is the `print` command. It'll switch between wanting parenthesis around the print statement, or not.

But when I run `python --version`, it always returns only **Python 3.5.1**. Anyone have a fix for this? It's getting annoying having to change my scripts every few times I run them.

Comment: You are not asking about syntax difference, you are asking about which python distribution you are using.

Comment: you could try doing `py -3 yourscript.py` or put `#! python3` at the top of your script

Comment: maybe you're running your scripts in a different way: starting them from a double click (file association) or  running them with the "python" prefix, not to mention the `#!/bin/env` shebang that could point on another distro.

Comment: You're running different versions of Python on your system. Make sure you always execute the same core binary. Unrelated, you should always use `print` with parenthesis (even tho it's not a function in Python 2) and you can do an easy `try: input = raw_input; except NameError: pass` and just use `input` to make sure you always get the proper `input` regardless of the interpreter it runs on.

Comment: putting #! python3 at the top of my scripts, seems to run them in python 3 consistently.

I do run them in different ways as well, I have a mainframe script with commands to launch my other scripts coded in, didn't realize that would effect anything. I'm still fairly new to python. However, adding the #! python3 to the top of all my scripts including my mainframe script, seems to still run them in python3 regardless of how I launch them.

Comment: How are you launching them?